# How to search for a column with input parameters and update that column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a TABLE like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST5 ([Id] INT, [A] BIT, [B] BIT, [C] BIT, [D] BIT, [E] BIT);
INSERT INTO TEST5 ([Id], [A], [C], [E]) VALUES (1, 'true', 'false', 'true')
INSERT INTO TEST5 ([Id], [A], [B], [C]) VALUES (2, 'true', 'true', 'true')
INSERT INTO TEST5 ([Id], [C], [D], [E]) VALUES (1, 'false', 'false', 'true')
```

What I want to do is to create a procedure such that it accepts parameters (id INT, column char(1)). If the cell matched by id and column is true/false, I am to invert it. Else, no changes is made.
This is what I have done but couldn't run. I am using mysql.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE invertValue(
    id INT,
    column char
)
BEGIN
UPDATE TABLEDB
SET column = SELECT a,b,c,d,e 
CASE column =
WHEN column = 'false' THEN 'true'
WHEN column = 'true' THEN 'false'
WHERE Id = id
END;
```

But all I have are syntax errors. Please help!

Comment: are you using SQL server or mysql?

Comment: In Sql server you would have used dynamic sql, that is inside the procedure you would have created a sql statement using the given column and executed it inside the procedure but I don’t think that is possible with MySQL. You might have to re-think your solution

Comment: mysql but I am a beginner.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Is there any way I could have done it in MySQL with the aforementioned requirements?

Comment: I think you need to try to solve this in another way

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are mixing MS Sql and mysql.

To flip the `BIT` value when `ID` matches, you can try like following.

```
UPDATE TEST5
SET A=NOT A, B= NOT B, C=NOT C, D=NOT D, E = NOT E
WHERE ID=1;
SELECT * FROM TEST5
```

There are few issues in your query.

1. Don't use [] for the column name in mysql.
2. BIT can hold only 0 or 1, not 'true' and 'false'
3. You don't need input parameter 'column'
4. Don't use reserved keywords as parameter name, like 'column'.

[Demo](https://rextester.com/TEDGB23185)

**Edit:**

To choose dynamic column, you need to build dynamic sql like following.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE invertValue(
    id INT,
    clm char
)
BEGIN
SET @t1 =CONCAT("UPDATE TEST5 SET ",clm,'= not ', clm," where ID=",id);
 PREPARE stmt3 FROM @t1;
 EXECUTE stmt3;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;

END;
```

[**SP Demo Online**](https://rextester.com/DDQXR9483)

Try minimizing the risk of  [**SQL Injection Vulnerability**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection), by parameterized dynamic query like following.

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE invertValue(
    id INT,
    clm char
)
BEGIN

  SET @t1 := concat('UPDATE TEST5 SET `', clm,'` = not `', clm, '` where id= ? ');   
  SET @id := id;
  PREPARE stmt FROM @t1;
  EXECUTE stmt USING @id;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END;
```

Comment: Only one column is to be changed, not all

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I have a question. Let's say I don't want to invert all the BITs in all the columns, but only for some columns, is there anyway to do it with a procedure?

For example, I want to invert only Id = 1 with input column a. How do I do it? I can't think of any other way without a procedure.

Comment: I have updated the answer, you can have a look, I have changed column to clm as column is reserved key word.

Comment: @WeitingChen are you still weiting to mark the answer :)